How to properly handle back button in nested WillPopScope widgets in Flutter
I'm working on a Flutter application with a NavigationPage that uses an IndexedStack to manage different screens with a BottomNavigationBar. Each screen is wrapped in a Navigator with its own GlobalKey. My issue is with handling the back button press on the ManagementScreen.
Here's how I currently manage the back button press in the NavigationPage:
class NavigationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavigationPageState createState() => _NavigationPageState();
}

class _NavigationPageState extends State<NavigationPage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool isKeyboardVisible = false; // Update this based on keyboard visibility
  List<GlobalKey<NavigatorState>> _navigatorKeys = [
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    // Add more keys if you have more tabs
  ];

  Future<bool> systemBackButtonPressed() async {
    if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
      return Future.value(true); // Exit the app or handle it as needed
    } else {
      var currentState = _navigatorKeys[_selectedIndex].currentState;
      if (currentState != null && currentState.canPop()) {
        currentState.pop();
        return Future.value(false);
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = 0;
        });
        return Future.value(false);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: systemBackButtonPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: _navigatorKeys.map((key) {
            return Navigator(
              key: key,
              onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => getPage(_selectedIndex),
                );
              },
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Visibility(
          visible: !isKeyboardVisible,
          child: BottomNavBar(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onItemTapped: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getPage(int index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return HomeScreen();
      case 1:
        return ManagementScreen();
      // Add more cases if you have more tabs
      default:
        return HomeScreen();
    }
  }
}

And here's the code for my ManagementScreen:
class ManagementScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<bool> _onWillPop(BuildContext context) async {
    debugPrint("ManagementScreen onWillPop triggered");
    // Add any specific logic you want here
    return true; // or false to prevent the screen from popping
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;
    final width = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _onWillPop(context), //this not working
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            height: height * 1,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/app_background1.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // Your content here
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Issue:
The systemBackButtonPressed method in the NavigationPage works fine when the _selectedIndex is 0, but when navigating to the ManagementScreen, the onWillPop callback is not triggered. I expect the onWillPop method to be called when I press the back button on the ManagementScreen, but it doesn’t seem to be working as expected.

you can try using FutureBuilder

WillPopScope is depreciated.
You should change to using the recommended replacement widget PopScope, which has a slightly different (IMHO better) implementation.
You would typically use this in a StatefulWidget so you can change the value supplied to canPop when you want to.
class ManagementScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false, // <- Changing this to true will allow you to pop the route.
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) => debugPrint('didPop=$didPop'),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

